# Python TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SingleBlockManager'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would appreciate any input. I was previously able to obtain image using this code but going back through my work it is now giving me this error. Any ideas how I can fix this?Perhaps this is due to upgrading matplotlib recently?

**Code I am using**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as ss
%matplotlib notebook
n = df.shape[1]
year_means = df.mean(axis=1)
year_std = df.std(axis=1)/(np.sqrt(n))
yerr = year_std * 1.96
y= 37000
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1.96,vmax=1.96)
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('seismic')
colors = pd.DataFrame([])
colors['intensity'] = norm((year_means-y) / year_std)
colors['color'] = [cmap(x) for x in colors['intensity']]
plt.figure()
bar_plot = plt.bar(range(df.shape[0]), year_means, yerr = yerr, color = colors['color']);
hoz_line = plt.axhline(y=y, color='grey', linewidth=2, linestyle = ':');
y_text = plt.text(3.4, y, 'y = %d' %y, bbox=dict(fc='white',ec='k'));
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index, alpha = 0.8);
```

### **Error Message I am receiving**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6b68c0797acf> in <module>()
      2 cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('seismic')
      3 colors = pd.DataFrame([])
----> 4 colors['intensity'] = norm((year_means-y) / year_std)
      5 colors['color'] = [cmap(x) for x in colors['intensity']]
      6 plt.figure()

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SingleBlockManager'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix. Apparently you cannot call a matplotlib.colors.Normalize with a dataframe any more in matplotlib 2.2. Use the values instead I updated line 4 to

```
colors['intensity'] = norm(((year_means-y) / year_std).values)
```